# Ruby mysql2 error when executing statements in rapid succession

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I have a strange issue using the Mysql2 client in Ruby. When trying to execute the following:

```
client.query("CREATE DATABASE ...; INSERT INTO ..."); #SQL truncated for brevity
client.query("SELECT 1 FROM ...") #SQL truncated for brevity
```

Ruby throws an error that the table I'm selecting from doesn't exist. However if I try the following:

```
client.query("CREATE DATABASE ...; INSERT INTO ..."); #SQL truncated for brevity
sleep 1
client.query("SELECT 1 FROM ...") #SQL truncated for brevity
```

The query works with no problems. It seems as though I need to give the MySQL server some time to load the data before I'm able to query it. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to programmatically overcome this without using sleep?

**Update**

I initialize the client as so:

```
Mysql2::Client.new({
                       :adapter => "mysql2",
                       :host => ip_address,
                       :username => db_username,
                       :password => db_password,
                       :flags => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS
                   })
```

I checked the 'query_options' attribute and async is set to false. I have tried explicitly setting the async => false flag to no avail.

The same issue happens if I use

```
Model.connection.execute(SQL HERE)
```

Note, this is all executed from within a Rails unit test.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have `autocommit` set properly (`true`), but mess somehow with [async](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#async) in [options](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#cascading-config). Would you please either post all the connection-related code (starting with `Mysql2::Client.new`), or check if explicit set `client.query("CREATE …", :async => false)` helps?

Comment: You shouldn't need to insert any waits. We use MySQL extensively, and at full speed. Ours was installed using a standard repo, with the standard settings, however we use the Sequel ORM with either the mysql or mysql2 drivers.

Comment: I agree that that's weird. It looks like you could just fold both queries into a single multistatement `client.query` call.

Comment: What happens when you remove  Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS ?

Comment: Also, could you post the error?

Comment: Is there a typo in this question?  Should it be CREATE _TABLE_ instead of CREATE **DATABASE**?

Comment: Have you discovered your problem? If so please answer your own question. If not, add the info other people asked, like the error, and etc.

Comment: No, it should be 'DATABASE' as the functionality creates entirely new databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the only thing that ended up working and not needing the `sleep 1` in between is the following:

```
@model = Model.new    
Mysql2::Client.default_query_options[:connect_flags] |= Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS
@model.connection.reconnect!
```